# How can create right menu sidebar on google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sidebar

I want create menu sidebar on google map and onclick show menu description

right menu sidebar
[image: right menu sidebar]

show menu description if onclick
[image: show menu description]

I do this but menu fix on right window on browser. I want show menu on google map
[image: I do this]

How can I learn how to do.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not connected the maps it's just a positioned html element.

something like this:

```
#rpanel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -180px;
  top: 200px;
}

#rpanel:hover {
  right: 0;
}

<div id="rpanel">im in the right</div>
```

Comment: it have scrollbar on below. can hide it ?
Thanks